# SQL Server activity monitor show all queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, monitoring

I'm using SQL Server 2005, and I'd like to know if there is any possibility to watch every query sent to SQL server?

SQL Server Management Studio has a built-in tool called the Activity Monitor which gives me nearly what I am searching for in the "Recent Expensive Queries Pane"

This pane shows information about the most expensive queries that have been run on the instance over the last 30 seconds.

I need exactly this for all recent queries, not just the expensive ones...

Can anyone help me?

Name a tool, or give me a hint what to search for...

Comment: Check out: [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) - that's exactly what you're looking for!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To watch every query sent to SQL server using SQL profiler, you can use one of SQL Profiler predefined templates. It's TSQL_Duration.

[image]

It's designed to track completed stored procedures and TSQL code.

[image]

The trace will show you exactly the batch executed.

[image]

You can expand the events tracked and columns shown.You can find more information here: [How To: Use SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx)

The same feature is also available in [ApexSQL Comply](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_comply.aspx), an auditing tool that uses SQL traces to capture the events, then stores them in a central repository database, and provides built-in and custom reports where you can easily filter the transactions, and export them as Excel, Word, or PDF files.

[image]

[image]
*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: Although this is an old Question, i will change the accepted answer to yours, because it's better and a more complete one.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), it's usually installed along with SSMS.

Comment: Thank you very much!
That's exactly what i was looking for. 
It required some time to filter the results enought to get the data but its worth the effort!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Profiler in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) is good here is how to go about doing it:

[Monitor all queries](https://dynamicconsulting.com/2016/02/03/analyzing-select-statements-using-sql-server-profiler/)

Tools >> SQL Server Profiler

You connect to your server, then start with profiling template: Blank

Then in the Event Selection Tab select **show all events** and **show all columns**.

Then Scroll down and expand the Performance area, and select checkboxes:

ShowplanAll

ShowplanXML

Then scrolldown to Stored Procedures and check:

RPC: Starting

SP: StmtCompleted

SP: StmtCompleted

That should do it.

The **showplan All** is cool its top row gives SQL planner estimates for these costs:

EstimateRows EstimateIO   EstimateCPU  AvgRowSize   TotalSubtreeCost OutputList